# awk cumulative sum in on dimension

Tags: awk

Good afternoon,

I would like to make a cumulative sum for each column and line in awk.

My in file is  :

1   2   3   4
2   5   6   7
2   3   6   5
1   2   1   2

And I would like : per column

1   2   3   4
3   7   9   11
5   10  15  16
6   12  16  18
6   12  16  18

And I would like : per line

1   3   5   9   9
2   7   13  20  20

2   5   11  16  16
1   3   4   6   6

I did the sum per column as :

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) sum[i] += $i}; END { for (i in sum) printf "%s ", sum[i]; printf "\n"; }' test.txt  #  sum
```

And per line .

```
awk '
BEGIN {FS=OFS=" "}
{
sum=0; n=0
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
     {sum+=$i; ++n}
     print $0,"sum:"sum,"count:"n,"avg:"sum/n
}' test.txt
```

But I would like to print all the lines and columns.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, could you please let us know expected output and what is not working.

Comment: Please post it in your post in CODE TAGS not in comments please.

Comment: I am new sorry.

Comment: No need to be sorry, we all learn here, edit post and let us know then with correct expected output.

Comment: @CathyBreton, why the last line/column should be duplicated in both variants (ex. `6 12 16 18`)?

Comment: Bravo for improving your Q, but to make it really easy to read as code/data/output/errMsgs, use 4 spaces at the front of each line  OR highlight a block of text and use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box to format as `code/data/output/errorMsgs`. For more info see  [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Good luck.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest , I need the last line to sort my all matrix at the end.

Comment: @shellter, thanks , I have to learn the editing process.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have all the correct information available, all you are missing is the printout statements.

Is this what you are looking for?

**accumulated sum of the columns:**

```
 % cat foo
1 2 3 4
2 5 6 7
2 3 6 5
1 2 1 2
 % awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {sum[i]+=$i; $i=sum[i] }; print $0}' foo
1 2 3 4
3 7 9 11
5 10 15 16
6 12 16 18
```

**accumulated sum of the rows:**

```
 % cat foo                                                              
1 2 3 4
2 5 6 7
2 3 6 5
1 2 1 2
 % awk '{ sum=0; for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {sum+=$i; $i=sum }; print $0}' foo                                                                                                                                                                      
1 3 6 10
2 7 13 20
2 5 11 16
1 3 4 6
```

Both these make use of the following :

- each variable has value `0` by default (if used numerically)
- I replace the field `$i` with what the `sum` value
- I reprint the full line with `print $0`

Comment: Please be sure to accept the answer that best solves your problem, if any, by pressing the [checkmark sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) . This gives the respondent with the best answer 15 points of reputation. Yoe can also upvote any and all answers that help your understanding of your problem. Note that rep points are not subtracted (as some people seem to think) from the original-poster's reputation points ;-) .

Answer (score 2):

row sums with repeated last element

```
$ awk '{s=0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=s+=$i; $i=s}1' file

1 3 6 10 10
2 7 13 20 20
2 5 11 16 16
1 3 4 6 6
```

`$i=s` sets the index value (now incremented to NF+1) to the sum and `1` prints the line with that extra field.

columns sums with repeated last row

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) c[i]=$i+=c[i]}1; END{print}' file

1 2 3 4
3 7 9 11
5 10 15 16
6 12 16 18
6 12 16 18
```

`END{print}` repeats the last row

ps. your math seems to be wrong for the row sums

Comment: it's double assignment. for example `a=b=3` sets both `a` and `b` to `3`.  Or you can write it `a=3; b=3`.

Comment: Hy @karakfa , something that I don't understand. c[i]=$i+=c[i], why two =

Comment: Ok, thank's , I was trying to edit my post correctly. Thank's a lot.

Comment: Can you explain me, it is woking well, but I am not able to undestand why we can double the last row or column. Thank's again.

Comment: added explanation, these are "golfed" versions; clarity wasn't a goal.